# Remove spaces between numbers in column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, trim

I have a column in database which stores credit card number. But sometimes people enter credit card number like this 1234 5678 9123 4567 which causes a lot of problem for me while working with orders. So I tried to look up for some solution that I can use to remove spaces between the numbers but couldn't find any.

Before: 1234 5678 9123 4567

After: 1234567891234567

Comment: You should NOT BE storing CC Numbers in your own database this is a huge security risk.  You should be passing the CC number to your merchants API and storing the transaction ID to process, refund, etc.

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Agree with @Chris, storing card numbers without at least encrypting them is a risky business (and your card merchant would likely be concerned if they were to find out).

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET field=REPLACE(field, ' ', '');
```

Must not have searched very hard: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html
Your first stop should always be the documentation for the product you're using...

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Marc B answer. Instead of updating the table you can remove spaces when selecting

```
SELECT REPLACE(field, ' ', '') FROM yourtable
```